# Relative Change Calculation

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

```
  Prod  T1  T2   
    A   42  48  
    A   21  18  
    B   38  37  
    B   57  68  
    B   38  30  
    C   51  54  
    C   47  49  
    C   22  15
```

For each row I want to add relative change corresponding to each product. e.g for Row1 Change of Product A is ((48+18)-(42+21))/(42+21) = 4.7% and change for Row 1 is (48-42)/42= 14%. So in the new column I want to calculate 14% - 4.7% = 9.3%. i.e Actual Change % - Product Change %.
What is the best possible way to do this

Comment: Your data structure seems very risky for the calculations you intend to use. What would happen if your data is accidentally sorted? (that is, if the second and first rows exchanged positions). I think you can profit a lot from having an additional column that encodes the initial and final states, so if the data is messed up, you'll always be able to return to the original state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets `df` be your data.frame.

We calculate the change by row and the change by Product, creating new columns for this values. Then we do the calculations you need and only keep a new column called RelativeChange.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(by_row = (T2 - T1) / T1) %>% 
  group_by(Prod) %>% 
  mutate(by_prod = ( sum(T2) - sum(T1) ) / sum(T1),
         RelativeChange = by_row - by_prod) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(by_row, by_prod))
```